# R wanting to limit the amount of digits from csv file

Tags: r, truncate, read.csv, magrittr, kableextra

There are plenty of threads about people thinking they have lost digits when reading in a csv file, and it's just a digits setting that isn't displaying all of them.

I on the other hand want to round or truncate my incoming data to two decimal places. I am having an issue in Rmarkdown where I can't limit the decimal places after highlighting fields.

This has lead to me attempting to round before the highlighting, but that leads to undesirable results if I go lower than 4 places since I am working with numbers near 0. It'll also throw scientific numbers in from time to time....which just doesn't look clean in my table.

df.csv

```
     Sample   blank   square   stool   ball       triangle     circle    hammer     dog
 1:    16-ww3 0.00090 0.93100 0.01219 0.00006      0.00606      0.00180 0.00000 0.00003
 2:      17-e 0.00034 0.67452 0.00297 0.00006      0.00357      0.00172 0.00008 0.00001
 3:    21-r9a 0.00186 0.34577 0.01558 0.00020      0.02277      0.00586 0.00009 0.00012
 4:       7-d 0.00003 0.00352 0.01179 0.00003      0.01640      0.56326 0.00349 0.00064
 5:    7401-1 0.00151 0.55153 0.00196 0.00017      0.00055      0.00029 0.00012 0.00000
 6:    7401-2 0.00056 0.50825 0.00433 0.00010      0.00000      0.00008 0.00006 0.00003
```

Code

```
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

DF <- read.csv(file="df.csv"), header=TRUE, sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF[1:nrow(DF), 2:ncol(DF)] <- round(DF[1:nrow(DF), 2:ncol(DF)], 4)

paint <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x < 0.1, "white", ifelse(x < 0.2, "yellow", "red"))
}

DF %<>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) {
   cell_spec(x, background = paint(x), format = "latex") 
  })

kable(DF, caption = "Highlighted numbers near zero", digits = 2, format = "latex", booktabs = T, escape = F, longtable = T)%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "repeat_header", font_size = 6))%>%
  landscape()%>%
  row_spec(0, angle = 45)
```

Desired output

```
 numbers formatted like:  0.00  0.01  0.10  1.10  
 AND highlighted as described in the paint function
```

Comment: please add a reproducible example.  There's nothing we can do with `read.csv("df.csv")` without the file.

Comment: It is not clear what result you want to achieve. Please, add some example of the desired output.

Comment: Yes, cell_spec is what causes it. So I round in that first line after reading in the csv.  But it leads to 0's being displayed where I want it to display 0.00.

Comment: When I get back to a computer, I can copy and paste that first table into my desired output and truncate the numbers down to an x.xx format.  I didn't think it would be that big of a.deal, sorry. There just wasn't anyway to show the highlighting as well (that I'm aware of.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, this should work:

First let's convert your numeric columns into character vectors, with the required number of decimal places, using formatC

```
DF[, -1] = lapply(DF[, -1], formatC, format = 'f', flag='0', digits = 2)
```

Now we can apply the latex formatting using:

```
DF[,-1] = lapply(DF[,-1], function(x) cell_spec(x, background = paint(x), format = "latex"))
```

Note that `paint` still works on the character vectors, because the comparison to a numeric value coerces them to numeric.

Here's a complete reproducible example, demonstrating this in practice

```
set.seed(1234)
DF <- data.frame(V1 = sample(letters,10,T), V2 = abs(rnorm(10)), V3 = abs(rnorm(10)))
DF[, -1] = lapply(DF[, -1], formatC, format = 'f', flag='0', digits = 2)
DF[, -1] = lapply(DF[,-1], function(x) cell_spec(x, background = paint(x), format = "latex"))
#    V1                       V2                        V3
# 1   c   \\cellcolor{red}{0.51} \\cellcolor{yellow}{0.11}
# 2   q   \\cellcolor{red}{0.57}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.51}
# 3   p   \\cellcolor{red}{0.55}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.91}
# 4   q   \\cellcolor{red}{0.56}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.84}
# 5   w   \\cellcolor{red}{0.89}    \\cellcolor{red}{2.42}
# 6   q   \\cellcolor{red}{0.48} \\cellcolor{yellow}{0.13}
# 7   a   \\cellcolor{red}{1.00}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.49}
# 8   g   \\cellcolor{red}{0.78}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.44}
# 9   r \\cellcolor{white}{0.06}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.46}
# 10  n   \\cellcolor{red}{0.96}    \\cellcolor{red}{0.69}

kable(DF, caption = "Highlighted numbers near zero", 
  digits = 2, format = "latex", booktabs = T, escape = F, longtable = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", 
    "repeat_header", font_size = 6)) %>%
  landscape() %>%
  row_spec(0, angle = 45)

# \begin{landscape}
# \begin{longtable}{lll}
# \caption{\label{tab:}Highlighted numbers near zero}\\
# \toprule
# \rotatebox{45}{V1} & \rotatebox{45}{V2} & \rotatebox{45}{V3}\\
# \midrule
# \endfirsthead
# \caption[]{Highlighted numbers near zero \textit{(continued)}}\\
# \toprule
# \rotatebox{45}{V1} & \rotatebox{45}{V2} & \rotatebox{45}{V3}\\
# \midrule
# \endhead
# \
# \endfoot
# \bottomrule
# \endlastfoot
# \rowcolor{gray!6}  c & \cellcolor{red}{0.51} & \cellcolor{yellow}{0.11}\\
# q & \cellcolor{red}{0.57} & \cellcolor{red}{0.51}\\
# \rowcolor{gray!6}  p & \cellcolor{red}{0.55} & \cellcolor{red}{0.91}\\
# q & \cellcolor{red}{0.56} & \cellcolor{red}{0.84}\\
# \rowcolor{gray!6}  w & \cellcolor{red}{0.89} & \cellcolor{red}{2.42}\\
# \addlinespace
# q & \cellcolor{red}{0.48} & \cellcolor{yellow}{0.13}\\
# \rowcolor{gray!6}  a & \cellcolor{red}{1.00} & \cellcolor{red}{0.49}\\
# g & \cellcolor{red}{0.78} & \cellcolor{red}{0.44}\\
# \rowcolor{gray!6}  r & \cellcolor{white}{0.06} & \cellcolor{red}{0.46}\\
# n & \cellcolor{red}{0.96} & \cellcolor{red}{0.69}\\*
#   \end{longtable}
# \end{landscape}
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very much @dww. I have one follow on question that I'm guessing you might be able to help with.  In the paint function I have, how can I change it to exclude cells less than .1  As in, I don't want to change the color of those cells because it removes the striping of kable. I only want to colorize values yellow that are >=.1<.2 and red for values >=.2 I'm not sure how to leave the no option in cel_spec to allow no change to occur.